# dynamically set the date value in matdatepicker field affect the another matDatePicker field Date in Reactive Form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, mat-datepicker

I have two matDatePicker control (statement date and start date) in my reative form I have dynamically set the value of start date field based on statement date field value and number of month.

```
<div [formGroup]="parameters">
<div class="mat-field">
    <mat-form-field color="primary">
        <mat-label>Statement Date</mat-label>
        <input id="statementDate" matInput [matDatepicker]="statementDatePicker"  formControlName="statementDate"  (dateChange)="datechanged()" >
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="statementDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #statementDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="mat-field">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Start Date</mat-label>
        <input id="startDate" matInput [matDatepicker]="startDatepicker" formControlName="startDate" readonly [disabled]="parameters.value.period!='other'">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #startDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="mat-field">

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Period</mat-label>
        <mat-select id="period" matInput formControlName="period" (selectionChange)="datechanged()">
            <mat-option value="12">12 Months</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="11">11 Months</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="10">10 Months</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="9">9 Months</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="8">8 Months</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="7">7 Months</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="6">6 Months</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="5">5 Months</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="4">4 Months</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="3">3 Months</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="2">2 Months</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="1">1 Month</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="other">other</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

ts file

```
 export class DatepickerMinMaxExample {
 parameters: FormGroup

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.parameters = new FormGroup({
      'statementDate': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'startDate': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'period': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  });

  }
    
 public datechanged(){
    if(this.parameters.controls['statementDate'].value!=null&& this.parameters.controls['period'].value!=null&& this.parameters.controls['period'].value!='other'){
      let stmtDate=this.parameters.controls['statementDate'].value;
      let send_date=this.parameters.controls['statementDate'].value;
      console.log('statement date: '+ this.parameters.controls['statementDate'].value)
      let period=parseInt(this.parameters.controls['period'].value)
      let formattedDate : any;
   
      send_date.setMonth(send_date.getMonth()-period);
      send_date.setDate(send_date.getDate()+1);
      formattedDate=send_date.toISOString().slice(0,10);
      console.log('format date: '+ formattedDate)
      console.log('stment date after format date: '+ stmtDate)
      this.parameters.controls['startDate'].setValue(new Date(formattedDate))
    }

}
}
```

dynamically updating the start date value affect the statement date matDatePicker and value as well.
[image]

[image]

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/datepicker-min-date-bug-wavfqq?file=app%2Fdatepicker-min-max-example.html)

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public datechanged(){
    if(this.parameters.controls['statementDate'].value!=null&& this.parameters.controls['period'].value!=null&& this.parameters.controls['period'].value!='other'){
      this.parameters.controls['startDate'].setValue(new Date(this.parameters.controls['statementDate'].value))
      let startDate=this.parameters.controls['startDate'].value
      let period=parseInt(this.parameters.controls['period'].value)
      let formattedDate : any;
   
      startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth()-period);
      startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+1);
      formattedDate=startDate.toISOString().slice(0,10);
      this.parameters.controls['startDate'].setValue(new Date(formattedDate))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `stmtDate` and `send_date` in your `datechanged()` function are reference types, referring to `this.parameters.controls['statementDate'].value`. Consequently changing either of those two variables changes the date in your `statementDatePicker`.

Doing a deep copy of those two fields, using `cloneDeep` from [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) gets it to work.

```
      const _ = require("lodash");

      let stmtDate = _.cloneDeep(
        this.parameters.controls["statementDate"].value
      );
      let send_date = _.cloneDeep(
        this.parameters.controls["statementDate"].value
      );
```

(Note: I opted for Lodash over traditional methods of deep copy such as the spread operator, `Object.assign()` and `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))` since they don't copy functions, while `cloneDeep` from Lodash does, and in your case your `send_date` variable is using functions such as `setMonth()`, etc.)

I forked your Stackblitz and made a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/datepicker-min-date-bug-mnwsgs?file=app/datepicker-min-max-example.ts)